# FB Like to status on my page

Tags: wordpress, facebook-like

I want to add a *Like* button to my page, but *Like* should belong to the fan page status, not to page I'm on it.

My idea is that I want to automatically add a link to a new article from WordPress to Facebook, and then I want the same like I have on Facebook, to have the amount of likes be synchronized.

Is it possible and how?

Comment: You cannot get like counts to synchronize for two different objects.  For the objects to be the same, they must be the same URL.  No way around this.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `href` attribute for a like button.

For example, this like button would like the Facebook page for Facebook:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://facebook.com/facebook" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Comment: yes but i need to specify to which status i need to do like button.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the URL from the status ID. You can find this by right-clicking on the "... Hours ago" link on every Facebook status (gray color).

This will now be the same `post_object`.